# Purpose of doctrine:mapping:convert while importing entities from existing database using Symfony2 and Doctrine2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In the Symfony2 [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html), the instructions says to do use the following command

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

followed by:

```
 php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeBlogBundle annotation
 php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

What is the purpose of doctrine:mapping:convert, I see that it generates the schema, but if I run ommit it and only run

```
 php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeBlogBundle annotation
 php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

it stills work.

Does doctrine:mapping:import check if schema is present in bundle and if not continues to import directly from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you ran `doctrine:mapping:convert` the xml mapping stay on the hard drive. So the next call to `doctrine:mapping:import` import the same schema. `doctrine:mapping:convert` should be ran again if you update the db and want to convert it to doctrine mapping file (i.e: update the xml schema).

Comment: The documentations for this section has changed in 2.3. I believe it was an error in the documentation. The recommended order for this commands has changed and, at least form me, it now makes more sense. It now gives the order you mention.